# Dropbox File Download/Upload

Tags: java, android, dropbox

I am having some issues with connecting dropbox to my app. I have printed the exception stack, and it shows that the error was caused by a dropboxunlinkedexception. I am not exactly sure what is wrong in my code. If anyone can take a look and help me figure out dropbox's API that would be great.

Full code:
http://pastebin.com/2ZAZgwEC

Dropbox relevant code:
http://pastebin.com/T2C1AiLz

Comment: I dont know about your problem but i fully recommend you to start searching on how to use the for loop!!! It will be very useful in your case based on your code lines...

Answer (score 0):

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start/setup#android

I think documentation is very clear about what to do integrate dropbox in your application.

Does your manifest file contains

```
<activity
  android:name="com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity"
  android:launchMode="singleTask"
  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard">
  <intent-filter>
    <!-- Change this to be db- followed by your app key -->
    <data android:scheme="db-INSERT-APP-KEY-HERE" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and also internet permission?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

dropboxunlinkedexception occurs when you try to download or upload a file without successful login. Check authentication part here https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start/authentication#android and this should sort your problem

Comment: This is the tutorial I based my code off off. My manifest contains both of those parts of code. It seems like the app keeps moving on before it asks me to authenticate with dropbox.

Comment: Okay i got ur problem. what u can do is just make a sample application place 2 buttons authenticate and download. Do authentication on authenticate button and download file on click of download button that should  work.